# UL list items stacking from the bottom instead of top

Tags: html, css

I have an ul that isn't stacking properly (or is, but not to my desired outcome.)

http://jsfiddle.net/rrrpy1rk/

html:

```
<ul id="footer_site_map">
        <li class="footer_parent"><a href="/pages/index/About">About</a>
            <ul class="footer_of_children">
                <li class="footer_children"><a href="/pages/index/Our%20Veterinarians">Our Veterinarians</a>
                </li>
                <li class="footer_children"><a href="/pages/index/Our%20Staff">Our Staff</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="footer_parent"><a href="/pages/index/Preventative%20Medicine">Preventative Medicine</a>
            <ul class="footer_of_children">
                <li class="footer_children"><a href="/pages/index/Puppies">Puppies</a>
                </li>
                <li class="footer_children"><a href="/pages/index/Kittens">Kittens</a>
                </li>
                <li class="footer_children"><a href="/pages/index/Adult%20Care">Adult Care</a>
                </li>
                <li class="footer_children"><a href="/pages/index/Senior%20Care">Senior Care</a>
                </li>
                <li class="footer_children"><a href="/pages/index/Rabbits">Rabbits</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="footer_parent"><a href="/pages/index/Surgical">Surgical</a>
            <ul class="footer_of_children">
                <li class="footer_children"><a href="/pages/index/Spaying">Spaying</a>
                </li>
                <li class="footer_children"><a href="/pages/index/Neutering">Neutering</a>
                </li>
                <li class="footer_children"><a href="/pages/index/Orthopedic%20Surgery">Orthopedic Surgery</a>
                </li>
                <li class="footer_children"><a href="/pages/index/Soft%20Tissue%20Surgery">Soft Tissue Surgery</a>
                </li>
                <li class="footer_children"><a href="/pages/index/Declawing%20Cat">Declawing Cat</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="footer_parent"><a href="/pages/index/Medical">Medical</a>
            <ul class="footer_of_children">
                <li class="footer_children"><a href="/pages/index/%20Complete%20Medical%20Assessment"> Complete Medical Assessment</a>
                </li>
                <li class="footer_children"><a href="/pages/index/Cardiology">Cardiology</a>
                </li>
                <li class="footer_children"><a href="/pages/index/Flea%20Treatment">Flea Treatment</a>
                </li>
                <li class="footer_children"><a href="/pages/index/Dentistry">Dentistry</a>
                </li>
                <li class="footer_children"><a href="/pages/index/Radiology">Radiology</a>
                </li>
                <li class="footer_children"><a href="/pages/index/Laboratory">Laboratory</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#footer_site_map {
    position:absolute;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
}
.footer_parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    height:20px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.footer_parent a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: MyriadProSemibold;
    font-size: 120%;
}
.footer_children {
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 200px;
}
.footer_children a {
    color: #FFF;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: ralewayregular !important;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.footer_of_children {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}
```

As seen from the fiddle the parent ul li's are stacking on top of the children ul li's. I need it to go the other way around.

Is there some easy fix, or should I re-structure it.

If you look at the fiddle, you may need to drag the bar to increase the size of the Result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addding `vertical-align: top;` to your .footer_parent fixes the issue:

```
.footer_parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```